# Libgdx/java Expression : m_type == b2_dynamicBody

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

im currently making a little game using Box2d and Libgdx. Every enemy is a box2d Dynamic body, hes killable so when hes dead i remove his body so :

```
            body.setUserData(null);

            gameScreen.lightManager.world.destroyBody(body);
```

On my Player does that works, even if i kill an enemy it works. But sometimes it suddenly crashes with this error exception :

```
Program: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin\javaw.exe
File: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/libgdx/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-     box2d/jni/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp, Line 299

Expression: m_type == b2_dynamicBody
```

Any idea why it crashes ? And What does the expression mean ? O.o

Comment: I think it may depend on when you are calling `destroyBody`, if this is during a contact event then it will probably be the cause of your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be sure that you are not removing body from World during World step - situation like this can take place when removing body is being processed in some asynchronous place of your app.

If you cannot avoid processing this asynchronous the easiest way to avoid the situation is to set to Body some UserData that will identify bodies to destroy and to destroy them directly after `world.step()` call - so instead of `remove()` just do

```
body.setUserData("DESTROY");
```

and then in your `render` method

```
world.step(timestep, 3, 3);

for(Body b : world.getBodies())
    if("DESTROY".equals(b.getUserData())
        world.destroyBody(body);
```